# Jenkins error com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated

Tags: jenkins

I am getting below error while sending test mail through outlook. SSL is disabled. While I am sending mail through Gmail it's OK, but not able to send mail through outlook because of below error:

> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [MA1PR0101CA0012.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]

I have configured:

- smtp server port: 587 and also checked 28
- User Name and password also configured.

While searching through Google I saw to set;

edit file: "/etc/default/jenkins"

sudo vim /etc/default/jenkins

add the line:

`JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true"` but I am not have etc in my program file/Jenkins. I assume if ssl is disabled then  this is not the error.

Comment: This has nothing to do with selenium. On the other hand MS does not allow direct mail sending through their SMTP server, you have to use the record from the MX records. See a bit more info here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_winother-mso_o365b/client-was-not-authenticated-to-send-anonymous/d405bcb0-f40c-42fa-b1b2-477597100123

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.